Classification of system of first order PDEs
What is the motivation behind classifying systems of first-order PDEs as elliptic, parabolic, or hyperbolic, and how does this relate to the concept of characteristic paths(paths along which the solution propagates)?

I remember these classifications being taught in my class. Our professor told us that this classification has nothing to with parabolas or hyperbolas or any geometry. I suppose, there is some motivation which comes from classification of quadratic forms. Anyways, I find it hard to believe that this question wasn't asked before.

What do you mean by first order? I associate those terms in your question to be primarily about the coefficients of second order differential operators.

@TheoDiamantakis By first order, I mean order of the highest derivative being one. There is a classification for first order systems as well just like the second order linear PDEs based on the quadratic forms. For example, Shallow water equations, Euler equations are hyperbolic.

This is just and idea, but there is some connection to second order equations. Heuristically $(\partial_t^2-c^2\partial_x^2)u=(\partial_t+c\partial_x)(\partial_t-c\partial_x)u$. So you might as well look for solutions to the first order system $(\partial_t \pm c\partial_x)u=0$. I assume this idea can be generalized to the vectorial case in higher dimensions, (possibly?) leading to the notion of "hyperbolic first order systems". I guess there is also a connection in the type of solutions we look for. As in, you can construct simple wave(!) solutions for conservation laws.

The classification of the second order PDEs is motivated by analyzing the nature of the roots of the characteristic equation derived from the quadratic form associated with the second-order PDE. This classification has profound implications for the behavior of solutions and their underlying geometry:
Elliptic equations: The characteristic quadratic form has no real roots, implying the absence of real characteristics (hypersurfaces along which solutions exhibit ODE-like behavior).
Parabolic equations: The quadratic form has coinciding real roots, leading to one characteristic.
Hyperbolic equations: The quadratic form has two distinct real roots, giving rise to two distinct families of real characteristics.
For systems of first-order PDEs, an analogous classification is based on the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the coefficient matrix:
Elliptic systems: No real eigenvalues are present.
Parabolic systems: Eigenvalues are real but lack a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors.
Hyperbolic systems: Eigenvalues are real, and there exists a complete set of linearly independent eigenvectors.
In somesense, the classification of system of first order PDE is the generalization of the classification of the second order PDEs, which is basically motivated by the underlying quadratic form.

Could you elaborate on your definition of a second order parabolic equation? Or provide a reference. As far as I know, parabolic requires more than a degenerate quadratic form. In order for it to have smoothing properties, I believe you have to be able to write it in the form $$\partial_{nn}^2u - \sum_{j,k=1}^{n-1}A^{jk}\partial^2_{jk}u = \text{ lower order terms}, $$ where $[A^{jk]$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Your answers appear to be correct only if there are only two independent variables.

@user531372 gives a nice answer for second order PDEs, which indeed is where the classification originated.
But some of it has been generalized to systems of PDEs of any order. I'll summarize the situation for a system of linear first order PDEs. Such a system on a domain $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ looks like this:
\begin{equation} Pu = A^i(x)\partial_iu(x) + B(x)u = f(x), \tag{*}\end{equation}
where $A^1, \dots, A^n, B$ are $k$-by-$k$-matrix-valued functions, $f$ is an $\mathbb{R}^k$-valued function, and $u$ is the $\mathbb{R}^k$-valued function we want to solve for.
Some such systems can be classified using their principal symbol, which is the $k$-by-$k$ matrix valued function given by
$$
\sigma(x, \xi) = A^i\xi_i\text{ for each }(x,\xi) \in D\times\mathbb{R}^n.
$$
The system (*) is called elliptic if for any $(x,\xi)\in D\times\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$,
$$ \det \sigma(x,\xi) \ne 0. $$
A solution to this system, as for one for a second order elliptic PDE, has strong regularity properties. For example, if $A^1, \dots, A^n, B$ are all smooth functions, then a solution to
$$ Pu = 0 $$
is always smooth.
If the system can be written as
$$ \partial_nu + A^1\partial_1u + \cdots + A^{n-1}\partial_{n-1}u + Bu = f, $$
and $A^1, \dots, A^{n-1}$ are all symmetric-matrix-valued functions, then the system is called symmetric hyperbolic.
If, on the other hand, for each $(x,\xi') \in D\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\backslash\{0\}$, the polynomial
$$ p(\xi_n) = \det \sigma(x,\xi) = \det (\xi_nI + A^1\xi_1+\cdots + A^{n-1}\xi_{n-1}) $$
has $k$ distinct real roots, the system is called strictly hyperbolic.
For these two types of hyperbolic systems, there is an initial value problem that can always be solved. The regularity of the solution depends on the regularity of the initial value of $u$. If the initial value of $u$ is not smooth, then the singularities propagate along curves known as characteristics.
I do not know any analogue of a second order parabolic PDE.
